# IntelliJ 2019.2 expecting to do the soft-wrap every time

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

When I run the application, logs are printing and it's not wrapped. So I have enabled View -> Active Editor -> Soft-Wrap.

It's wrapping it temporarily. If I try to run application again, it's not wrapping and again
I am enabling the soft-wrap.

Is there any permanent solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated tool bar button on the Run/Debug console to enable soft wraps. This setting is remembered. Or you can use the `Use soft wraps in console` option in `Preferences | Editor | General | Console`.